# Upload progress using pure PHP/AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, upload

I'm sure this has been asked before, but as I can't seem to find a good answer, here I am, asking... again. :)

Is there any way, using only a mixture of HTML, JavaScript/AJAX, and PHP, to report the actual progress of a file upload?

In reply to anyone suggesting SWFUpload or similar:

I know all about it. Been down that road. I'm looking for a 100% pure solution (and yes, I know I probably won't get it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to add PECL packages into your PHP, there is the [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) package.

The simplest way would be to just use swfupload, though.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, because the simplest way IS to just use SWFUpload. :)

Comment: the simpelest yes, but I think it does not qualify as "pure PHP/AJAX"? :)

Answer (score 5):

Monitoring your file uploads with PHP/Javascript requires the PECL extension:

> [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress)

A good example of the code needed to display the progress to your users is:

> [Uber Uploader](http://uber-uploader.sourceforge.net/)

If I'm not mistaken it uses JQuery to communicate with PHP.

You could also write it yourself, It's not that complex.

Add a hidden element as the *first* element of upload form, named `UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER`.

Poll a PHP script that calls `uploadprogress_get_info( UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER )`
It return an array containing the following:

```
time_start     - The time that the upload began (unix timestamp),
time_last      - The time that the progress info was last updated,
speed_average  - Average speed in bytes per second,
speed_last     - Last measured speed in bytes per second,
bytes_uploaded - Number of bytes uploaded so far,
bytes_total    - The value of the Content-Length header sent by the browser,
files_uploaded - Number of files uploaded so far,
est_sec        - Estimated number of seconds remaining.
```

Let PHP return the info to Javascript and you should have plenty of information.
Depending on the audience, you will likely not use all the info available.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [APC](http://www.php.net/apc) installed (and by this point, you really should; it'll be standard in PHP6), it has an option to enable upload tracking.
There's [some documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.rfc1867), and Rasmus has written a [code sample](http://progphp.com/progress.phps) that uses YUI.

Comment: This would be perfect, except it's not installed my server, and it's not thread safe, so there's no point really. Maybe in PHP6. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way, using only a mixture of HTML, JavaScript/AJAX, and PHP, to report the actual progress of a file upload?

I don't know of any way to monitor plain HTML (multipart/form-data) file uploads in webserver-loaded PHP.

You need to have access to the progress of the multipart/form-data parser as the data comes in, but this looks impossible because the ways of accessing the HTTP request body from PHP ([$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data) and [php://input](http://de.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)) are documented as being “not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"”.

You could do a script-assisted file upload in Firefox using an upload field's [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIDOMFileList) to grab the contents of a file to submit in a segmented or non-multipart way. Still a bunch of work to parse though.

(You could even run a PHP script as a standalone server on another port just for receiving file uploads, using your own HTTP-handling code. But that's a huge amount of work for relatively little gain.)

Comment: There is a PECL extension that does exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to five [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) a try it's a really cool solution for progress bar and it's not necesarely attached to php. Checkout also the other tools at digitarald.de

cheers

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, this is the problem that Web browsers should solve. We have progress meter for downloads, so why not for uploads as well?

Take a look at this for example:

http://www.fireuploader.com/

Comment: If you could include this functionality in all mayor browsers for us, it would be a very nice solutions. Until then, we will just have to work with the current limitations and build the functionality ourselves.