# PHP/ JS File Upload Progress Bar

Tags: php, javascript

How do I create a file upload progress bar similar to getdropbox.com using PHP and/or JavaScript?

Thanks, 
-Giles

Comment: See "Upload progress using pure PHP/AJAX?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653063/upload-progress-using-pure-php-ajax

Answer (score 2):

check http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-v525/index.html for a tutorial on this topic

Comment: This is not a good answer for Stackoverflow. It is a **link-only** answer and the contents of the link may not exist in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this is to use a Flash SWF to actually do the uploading and have it call javascript functions (using 'external interface') to update progress bars and so forth. There are a couple of projects out there for different javascript libraries, here is an example for jQuery: [here](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/)