# File upload progress bar: is flash-based the only way possible

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload progress using pure PHP/AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653063/upload-progress-using-pure-php-ajax)

I'm trying to have a file upload input field in my form and to have a status bar that shows upload progress as a percent and kb of the file. I keep seeing a lot of flash-based uploaders like swfupload. What non-flash alternatives are there that depend on js/jquery (no swf)

Comment: -1 No prior research shown. This is a "solved issue" without Flash, albeit with their own set of limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PHP has the APC extension installed then you can use it to get upload progress reports via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 1):

You should to use an iframe and form, if you setup what the frame are the target of the form, you can see an ajax effect. I use it, and solve all my problems